# CDO climate data operator stopped working in Cygwin (Win8)

Tags: cdo-climate

My Cygwin suddenly started to give problems running CDO commands:

```
cdo -sinfo file.nc
cdo    sinfo: Open failed on >file.nc<
              Unknown Error
```

I was operating on this file until few weeks ago. Both Cygwin and CDO should be up to date, so I'm failing to understand what's wrong:

```
$ cdo -V
Climate Data Operators version 1.9.8 (https://mpimet.mpg.de/cdo)
System: x86_64-unknown-cygwin
CXX Compiler: g++ -g -Wall -O2 -DPIC -pie -mwindows -ftree-vectorize -fopenmp
CXX version : g++ (GCC) 7.4.0
C Compiler: gcc -g -Wall -O2 -DPIC -pie -mwindows -ftree-vectorize -fopenmp
C version : gcc (GCC) 7.4.0
F77 Compiler: gfortran -g -O2
F77 version : GNU Fortran (GCC) 7.4.0
Features: 15GB 8threads C++14 Fortran DATA PTHREADS OpenMP HDF5 NC4/HDF5 OPeNDAP UDUNITS2 PROJ SSE2
Libraries: HDF5/1.10.2 proj/5.2.0
Filetypes: srv ext ieg grb1 grb2 nc1 nc2 nc4 nc4c nc5
     CDI library version : 1.9.8
 cgribex library version : 1.9.4
 ecCodes library version : 2.9.0
  NetCDF library version : 4.6.1 of May 26 2018 18:07:01 $
    hdf5 library version : 1.10.2
    exse library version : 1.4.1
    FILE library version : 1.8.3
```

and Cygwin:

```
$ uname -r
3.1.7(0.340/5/3)
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Given it is an unknown error, your best bet is to ask a question on the CDO website. The developers are normally responsive

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks a lot. Yes, I posted this question also there. I just wanted to get a broader public and have a quick reply...